# to find program in java

Tags: java

can we use two public classes in the same program.If not,why?

Comment: and what has the title to do with your question ?

Comment: No, I will not help you cheat on whatever online test you're taking.

Answer (score 2):

A **java source** file can only have **one** public **top level** class. In other words - each public top level class must be defined in its own file.

But an application usually consists of more then just one class and is usually written in more then one source file.

---

*Foo.java*

```
public class Foo {
}
public class Bar {  // this is a compile time error, 
}                   // Bar has to be defined in Bar.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Because Java is designed that way.

Why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Erm, is this a trick question.  You should be able to use as many public classes as you want within your program.

If this is not what you are finding then you may want to post either code or more explanation of what is actually happeing.

Code is always good.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many public classes as you want in your program. Could you be more specific about what your problem is?